# Instance variable, when re-initialised in sub class' initialization block, is overridden like instance method, which it should not

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have just started learning Java.I understand

1. Unlike instance method, instance variable can not  be overridden, and are not dynamically picked by JVM at run time when accessed polymorphically.
2. flow of execution : static block, super constructor, initialization block and      then constructor.

But I am stuck at one code, where I have polymorphically invoked a instance variable but its showing overridden value (which it should not show). The instance variable is overridden inside sub class' init block.

```
package package1;

public class Other {
    
    public static void main(String [] args){
            Parent referToChild = new Child();
            Parent referToChildTwo = new ChildTwo();
            System.out.println("age as referred by referToChild reference variable is:" + referToChild.age);// prints 35 (doubt 1)
            System.out.println("age as referred by referToChildTwo reference variable is:" + referToChildTwo.age);// prints 50 (doubt 2)
            System.out.println("money as referred by Other reference variable is:" + referToChild.money);
            //System.out.println("Other reference variable is:" + othObj.age);
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{
    // init block 
    {
        age = 35;
    }
}

class ChildTwo extends Parent{
    public int age;
    {
        age = 40;
    }
}

class Parent{
     public int age = 50;
     public int money = 100;
}
```

The answer I get is:

> 35
>
> 50
>
> 100

so my doubts are:

doubt 1 :Why is it showing "35", it should display super class' variable's value which is 50.

doubt 2 : When it is displaying sub class' variable's value for last case, then why not for this case.

Comment: This is why: http://ideone.com/QD1jbX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be overridden, but it is inherited by child classes as long as it wasn't private in the parent. And they can access it, including both reading and writing it.

Overriding is creating a new member which is part of the current class, which has the same definition of the member of the parent class, and for that member to be accessed when you use the object polymorphically.

For example:

```
class Parent {
   public int age = 50;
}

class Child {
   public int age = 80;
}
```

Here we defined a new member, `age`, which is separate from the parent's `age`. If you access it from inside `Child` using `this.age`, you'll get `80`. If you access the parent's `age` using `super.age`, you'll get `50`.

But this is not overriding, because if you use the object polymorphically, it will access the parent's `age`:

```
Child childObj = new Child();
Parent parentObj = childObj;

System.out.println( childObj.age ); // Will print 80
System.out.println( parentObj.age ); // Will print 50
```

This is despite the fact that they are both the same object. That's because the child **hides** the field rather than **override** it.

Simply assigning a value in a field inherited from the parent is not overriding. It's part of what inheritance is all about.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is it showing "35", it should display super class' variable's value which is 50.

The initializer block of subclass `Child` executes *after* the variable `age` is initialized in the `Parent` class. Therefore, `age` is first initialized to `50`, then to `35`.

This is explained in great detail in the Java Language Specification [Section 12.5 on Creation of New Class Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5), with the relevant part in bold:

> Just before a reference to the newly created object is returned as the result, the indicated constructor is processed to initialize the new object using the following procedure:
>
> 1. Assign the arguments for the constructor to newly created parameter variables for this constructor invocation.
> 2. If this constructor begins with an explicit constructor invocation (§8.8.7.1) of another constructor in the same class (using `this`), then evaluate the arguments and process that constructor invocation recursively using these same five steps. If that constructor invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason; otherwise, continue with step 5.
> 3. This constructor does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation of another constructor in the same class (using `this`). **If this constructor is for a class other than Object, then this constructor will begin with an explicit or implicit invocation of a superclass constructor (using `super`). Evaluate the arguments and process that superclass constructor invocation recursively using these same five steps**. If that constructor invocation completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason. Otherwise, continue with step 4.
> 4. **Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for this class**, assigning the values of instance variable initializers to the corresponding instance variables, in the left-to-right order in which they appear textually in the source code for the class. If execution of any of these initializers results in an exception, then no further initializers are processed and this procedure completes abruptly with that same exception. Otherwise, continue with step 5.
> 5. Execute the rest of the body of this constructor. If that execution completes abruptly, then this procedure completes abruptly for the same reason. Otherwise, this procedure completes normally.

As for the second question, `referToChildTwo` is declared of type `Parent`, while its actual type is `ChildTwo`. A `ChildTwo` instance has two `age` fields, the one defined in `ChildTwo` and the other one inherited from `Parent`.

When you write the expression `referToChildTwo.age`, the field inherited in `Parent` will be evaluated. To evaluate the one defined in the subclass, you would need to cast the variable, i.e. `((ChildTwo)referToChildTwo).age`.